# How to fix the ExampleInstrumentedTest error at "debug" to "release" switch?

Tags: android

Even the simpliest application displaying "Hello world" (I've just created a project in Android Studio 3.2.1 and didn't add a line of code), when I switch Build Variants from "debug" to "release" the ExampleInstrumentedTest I getting the error in  the ExampleInstrumentedTest already at import stage:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

screenshot: https://yadi.sk/d/tqpOqahoER9r7Q

If I return to "debug" - everything becomes perfect again: https://yadi.sk/d/1nKRraRqEnv2Bg

In the build.gradle (Module:App) dependencies:

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

exists https://yadi.sk/d/U_1HzgA1AONgoA

How is possible to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

unit tests are not meant to run in `release` mode.

in best cause you could change the test build-type; for example:

```
testBuildType "staging"
```

I'd doubt this would work with `release`, since that build-type has to inherit from build-type `debug`.